# Professional term for "useless: should be omitted"

Tags: synonyms, offensive-language

I need a way to say something is *useless*, in that including it is actually *harmful*, but not so harshly.

As in,

> "The last sentence is **useless** and should be omitted"

Where the last sentence in a paragraph is run-on, blather, useless, not interesting, misleading, something like that, kind of like this one ;)

Comment: How did *Thesaurus redundicus* answer such queries?

Comment: did you attempt to look "useless" up in an online thesaurus before asking? What did you find there? Why did it not meet your needs?

Comment: This question clearly doesn't meet SE quality standards, it's easily answered with a thesaurus.

Comment: What about "off topic or not constructive" like we see with closed questions on SE.

Comment: @BrandonBertelsen We also have the *general reference* close reason here on EL&U.

Comment: It wasn't meant as tongue in cheek :)

Comment: Better use the actual word that expresses your idea. There are worse things you can say than "X is useless".

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Consider *[extraneous](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/extraneous)*, "Not belonging to, or dependent upon, a thing; without or beyond a thing; foreign", and synonyms like *[superfluous](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/superfluous)* ("in excess of what is required or sufficient") or *[pleonastic](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/pleonastic)* ("Using an excessive number of words"). 
Other synonyms of superfluous include *excessive, extra, supernumerary, surplus, unnecessary, extravagant*, some of which apply.

Comment: I like superfluous

Comment: Definitely not pleonastic, since they'd need a dictionary to know what you mean (and maybe not even a common dictionary, considering my OS is highlighting that word as "misspelled").

Comment: @BrendanLong, Yes, pleonastic may be a new word to some people, but since everybody (on ELU, anyway:) knows the word *[pleonasm](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/pleonasm)* ("Redundancy in wording") I thought it might not be too far out of the way.

Comment: I'm *only* upvoting because of **superfluous**. We don't know exactly how much negativity OP's original "useless" is supposed to convey, but most likely it's a bit more than comes through with *unnecessary*. All the other suggestions are just a bit off the beaten track.

Comment: @FumbleFingers, my own preference is for *extraneous* rather than *superfluous*, as it expresses (I think) both superfluity and undesirability. *Superfluous* expresses lack of necessity for something, or its uselessness, but I think comes short of connoting wrong or harmful.  You disagree, perhaps?  Anyhow, both terms are much better known than *pleonastic*, which I mentioned because it denotes a surplus of words and connotes the undesirability of that surplus.

Comment: @jwpat7: On reflection I can see the justification for either - both words have very similar connotations here. I still think *superfluous* would be used more often (if only because it's a more common word). I'm reading "useless" as primarily *"serving no purpose"*, rather than *"damaging by its very presence".*

Answer (score 6):

My preference in this instance would be to use either ***prejudicial*** or ***detrimental*** as they convey the sense of 'harmful' as requested.

Comment: +1 for *[detrimental](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/detrimental#Adjective)*; but *[prejudicial](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/prejudicial)* may have harsher overtones than OP desires.

Comment: @jwpat7 Thanks. I felt that 'prejudicial' conveyed the required professional sense of 'harmful.' There are varying degrees of prejudice and I never thought it particularly harsh.

Comment: @TonyBalmforth, seems like prejudice would have overtly negative assumptions attached to it in a general and professional sense though.

Comment: @ardentsonata I still quite like it. It doesn't seem any more negative than either 'useless' or 'harmful' but perhaps it's me!

Answer (score 5):

Sometimes English just doesn't contain a word with the precise meaning you desire.

That said, I offer *irrelevant* and *unnecessary* as options. I would contend that both are semantically equivalent to *useless* (which--as Jeff Atwood points out--is a still a perfectly good word for your situation), but they tend more to the negative in my mind.

Answer (score 4):

I use *redundant* when someone has written something repetitive and unnecessary.

Answer (score 2):

You could say, "Your last sentence detracts from an otherwise good paragraph. I think your point would be better made by deleting that sentence."

Answer (score 1):

I've seen *surplusage* used in similar contexts. Strictly it just means *superfluous*, but 'where it is not necessary to have a sentence, it is necessary not to have a sentence.'

Answer (score 0):

I would say the last sentence *distracts from the intention* of the paragraph and should be omitted.

Answer (score 0):

In general, the sense of "useless" is that of something which will not bring any result (good or bad), in your example it seems that it is not the case of being useless, as using that sentence could result in a bad outcome.

You could say that the sentence is "not constructive", meaning that it is not going to bring about anything good and could actually do some harm if used.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest “irrelevant to the content/subject matter.” My old English professor would just call it “verbal deadwood.” So, in comparison, “useless: should be omitted” actually sounds kind.

Answer (score 0):

How about "last sentence is ineffectual — delete"?

Answer (score 0):

You can use *crap*:

> The last sentence is crap and should be removed.

It gives you quite a bit of room to think later on what you meant by *crap* and how you wish to express the disapproval.

Also, you can also use *dispensable*:

> The last sentence is dispensable and should be removed.

Comment: If the OP thinks *useless* is too harsh, how the heck would *crap* be an improvement?

Answer (score 0):

How about *ignored*? The last sentence may be ignored for the better. say it diplomatically.